# Resources in php are external

Tags: php

From the [PHP documentation for resource type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

> A resource is a special variable, holding a **reference to an external**
>   resource.

A statement I have ignored for years. `mysql_*`, `curl_*` etc.

Why are they called external?  Is it because they are add-on libraries? What of `fopen()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this manual page on resource types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/resource.php) `fopen()` is also included in the list of external resources and is filed under stream.

I believe they are called external because they are just that, a resource that has come from outside the core of PHP, such as a database, a file or an ftp connection. Rather than an internal resource like an array, a string or a integer.